# ASP.NET MVC Why doesn't this post action get called from the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In a system that uses Identity framework for authentication, I have the following Model, Controller action, and View respectively to implement a password change feature (I saw many articles for learning how to reset a password, but not how to change a password even though the current one is known):

**Model:**

```
public class ChangePasswordBindingModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string OldPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "New password")]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller action in `AccountController.cs`:**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePasswordBindingModel loginChange)
{

    IdentityResult fffx = await UserManager.ChangePasswordAsync("userId", loginChange.OldPassword, loginChange.NewPassword);
    return View("Index");
}
```

**View for password change form, called `ChangePassword.cshtml`:**

```
@model IdentityDevelopment.Models.ChangePasswordBindingModel
@{ ViewBag.Title = "ChangePassword";}
<h2>Change Password</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangePassword","Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    //@Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    <input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="@ViewBag.returnUrl" />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Current Password</label>
        @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.OldPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>New Password</label>
        @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.NewPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Re-enter New Password</label>
        @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

Why would clicking on the "Save" button on the form not call the post action method?

**EDIT 1:**

I am including the controller method for Login, in where a scenario causes the ChangePassword form to appear. Maybe there is something here that is a problem?

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel details, string returnUrl)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       AppUser user = await UserManager.FindAsync(details.Name,
                    details.Password);
        if (user == null)
         {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid name or password.");
          }
      else
       {

    //Check if this is initial login of user, force password change if so
                    PasswordChangeChecker PassCheck = new PasswordChangeChecker();
                    string userId = user.Id.ToString();
                    bool proceed = PassCheck.IsPasswordChangedFromInitial(userId);
                    if (proceed)
                    {
                        ClaimsIdentity ident = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user,
                                             DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                        ident.AddClaims(LocationClaimsProvider.GetClaims(ident));
                        ident.AddClaims(ClaimsRoles.CreateRolesFromClaims(ident));
                        AuthManager.SignOut();
                        AuthManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
                        {
                            IsPersistent = false
                        }, ident);


                        //persist login into db
                        Loginobject login = new Loginobject();
                        login.Username = user.UserName;
                        login.SessionId = HttpContext.Session.SessionID;
                        Session["sessionid"] = HttpContext.Session.SessionID;
                        login.Date = DateTime.Now;
                        SQLLoginrecord sqlLogin = new SQLLoginrecord();
                        sqlLogin.PutOrPostLogin(login);

                        TempData["LoginMsg"] = "Any existing sessions are now deactivated.";

                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return View("ChangePassword", new ChangePasswordBindingModel());
                    }
                }
            }
            ViewBag.returnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View(details);
        }
```

**EDIT 2:**

It looks like the cause of the issue is a global custom authorization filter (thanks for the comment stephen.vakil) `[AuthorizeSingleLogin]` that I have put over the definition of `AccountController.cs`

**AuthorizeSingleLogin.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace IdentityDevelopment.Infrastructure
{
    public class AuthorizeSingleLogin : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private AppIdentityDbContext db = new AppIdentityDbContext();
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            bool isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

            string user = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;

            string access = httpContext.Session.SessionID;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(user) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(access))
            {
                return isAuthorized;
            }

            SQLLoginrecord sqlLogin = new SQLLoginrecord();

            return sqlLogin.IsLoggedIn(user, access);
        }
    }
}
```

**SQLLoginrecord.cs**

```
using IdentityDevelopment.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using static IdentityDevelopment.Models.Loginobject;

namespace IdentityDevelopment.Infrastructure
{
    public class SQLLoginrecord
    {

        private LoginobjectDBContext db = new LoginobjectDBContext();
        private bool PriorSessionActive = false;
        public void PutOrPostLogin(Loginobject login)
        {
            var logins = db.Loginobjects.Where(l => l.Username == login.Username);

            if (logins.Any())
            {
                Loginobject tempLogin = logins.First();
                tempLogin.SessionId = login.SessionId;
                tempLogin.Date = login.Date;
                db.Entry(tempLogin).State = EntityState.Modified;
                PriorSessionActive = true;
            }
            else
            {
                db.Loginobjects.Add(login);
            }
            db.SaveChanges();


        }

        public bool IsLoggedIn(string user, string session)
        {
            var logins = db.Loginobjects.Where(l => l.Username == user && l.SessionId == session);

            if (logins.Any())
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public bool PriorSessionUpdated()
        {
            return this.PriorSessionActive;
        }


    }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: So, what happens when the button is clicked? Have you debugged?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Do you have any js code which is intercepting the submit button.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid yes I have debugged by placing a breakpoint in the post method in the controller. When I click the button, I get redirected to the index page, but it is not because of the call to Index in this post method, it is from somewhere else.

Comment: @Shyju no there is no javascript interference on the button anywhere.

Comment: if you are not getting 404 http response, it means you application is routing the call to a valid controller/action somehow. just out of instinct tho ... I believe it's the debugging that might not be working. trying changing the return view("index") to a view that doesn't exist ...

Comment: @Sam.C I tried that, it still returned to the Index page.

Comment: Do you have a global auth filter or some unusual routing tables that might explain this behavior?

Comment: @stephen.vakil Yes, and that is the issue. After commenting it out, the debug point is hit. It is a custom authorization filter to restrict actions to single sessions. Why would it cause the post method to not be called?

Comment: @stephen.vakil  I think I understand the problem now. Looks like the authorization of the global custom authorization filter returned false, since the login never went through the authorization processing of a successful login, therefore causing the post method to never get called, since it is under the control of the authorization filter (global filter not shown in my question) returning true. Thanks stephen.vakil, and if you could post your reply as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your action is not being hit on post and it is instead going elsewhere, that would lead me to believe that one of two things is happening:

1. Your routing tables are configured incorrectly
2. You have a global filter (especially a global authorization filter) that is interfering with your intended behavior by intercepting the request and disallowing or overriding it.

Through debugging and trial an error, you should be able to determine the culprit in either case.

Answer (score 3):

Your

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
```

element needs to be an

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save"/>
```

element.

Comment: Is there any documentation on why both types are submit but act differently?

Comment: I tried this out however it did not hit the breakpoint of the post method either.